# What OS X events can I access programmatically from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

I'd like to find both current running programs (or at least program in the foreground) programmatically - and also key events on OS X.

I found [inter-application communication guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_InterapplicationCommunication/_index.html), but they don't seem to say I can find out what applications are running.

I've found [key events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html), but it seems to imply that the current task in the forefront is the one that gets the key events and only if it doesn't handle them does it go up to event chain. I'd like to programmatically intercept them.

Seems dubious, I know. I'm trying to use key events along with screen captures to try to best learn text on the screen - it's for research.

I'm using swift, but I understand that an obj-c example is pretty helpful since they all use the same libraries.

Comment: Are you familiar with using Apple Script at all? There are plenty of resources showing what you can / can't access, and it is hand-in-hand with Swift. Let me try and find you a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of running applications use:

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications
```

You can build a key logger (so to speak) by creating an [event monitor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html) (same document you linked, just a different section).